# Count parameter in MPI_Bcast

Tags: mpi, openmpi

`MPI_Bcast (&buffer,count,datatype,root,comm)`

The tutorial at https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/ says that **count** - *Indicates the number of data elements of a particular type to be sent*.

What does that mean? Does it mean that -

1. **count** copies of the `buffer` array will be sent

   **OR**
2. **count** elements of the `buffer` is to be sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the second one. `count` elements of `sizeof(datatype)` will be sent.